# bpftrace and sys_read syscall

Tags: system-calls, bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I'm attempting to write a single bpftrace script which grab the strings passing from a postfix process and a saslauthd for the authentication part. The goal is detect compromise account of my company. The strace command give me some good results:

```
strace -p PID -s 100 -e 'read'
read(7, "\0\20", 2)                     = 2
read(7, "xxxxxxxxxx", 10)               = 10
read(7, "\0\t", 2)                      = 2
read(7, "YYYYYYYYY", 9)                 = 9
read(7, "\0\4", 2)                      = 2
read(7, "smtp", 4)                      = 4
```

I can recover login/password and detect if there is a bruteforce running.

but I try to have the same results with bpftrace with:

```
$ bpftrace -e 'kprobe:sys_read /comm=="saslauthd"/ {printf("%<%s>\n",str(arg1,arg2));}'
<>
<login>
<>
<>
<>
<smtp>
```

In this case, I can read some sys_read syscall strings but not all. I don't understand why my bpftrace doesn't have the same result. 
I also think about the null character and that why i use *str(arg1,arg2)* to force the size of the array. I'v also tried to use tracepoint and this is the same result.

Maybe someone can help me to understand where is my error ? So any input will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR.** That's actually the expected behavior of `str(buf, len)`. It retrieves the string pointed to by `buf`, with a limit to `len` characters including the NULL character. Thus, since in your case some strings start with a NULL character, `str()` will copy an empty string.

---

**Sources.** bpftrace [translates](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/commit/c0e96c15363adb601b9ca1f8b1650b0a6dfd086b) `str()` into a call to the `BPF_FUNC_probe_read_str` BPF helper. [In the kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=a5e8c07059d0f0b31737408711d44794928ac218), that helper itself calls `strncpy_from_unsafe`.

I don't think bpftrace already has a function implementing what you're looking for. If you want your described semantics, you could ask for a `copy()` function in bpftrace. Though, looking at [the commit that introduced `str()`](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/commit/c0e96c15363adb601b9ca1f8b1650b0a6dfd086b), it shouldn't be too hard to write a patch for that. Don't hesitate to send a pull request!

Comment: Many thanks for your response, you confirmed my suspicions about the str() function of bpf with some effectives facts. I will study the commit that you post and after that try to send a pull request.

Comment: If/when your pull request is accepted, please post here so that I update my answer.